# Sublime Text 3: how to change the size of tabs?

Tags: css, sublimetext3

I'm using ST3 (build 3103) on OS X.

I have this set in my user preferences:

```
...
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
...
```

but when I open *.css files hitting the tab key *always* inserts 4 spaces instead of two.

I've tried creating a css-specific settings file (CSS.sublime-settings) with the following but, even after a restart, I'm still seeing 4 spaces when I tab.

```
{
  "tab_size": 2,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Reopened qestion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check tab size in the bottom right corner of ST window. Try Select All and then changing tab size.